# Using dicts to look up values for DataFrame variables

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns Teacher_ID and Student_ID. I also have dicts for each, TDict and SDict, giving, say, the grade in which each teacher teaches and the grade each student is enrolled in, with their ID numbers as the keys.

I want to create a new column in my DataFrame referencing the information in the dicts. But when I try to create a column with a formula something like TDict[Teacher_ID] + SDict[Student_ID], I get an error message telling me that "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed."

What's the approved way around this? Do I have to copy the ID's into new columns, replace the values in those columns with the dict values, and then work from there? I'm guessing there's a better way....

Comment: Can you show an example of your code and data structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you can simply call `map`:

```
df['Teaching_grade'] = df['Teacher_ID'].map(TDict)
df['Student_grade'] = df['Student_ID'].map(SDict)
```

This will perform the lookup and assign the value to the new column

Comment: Thanks very much, and yes, this does create a column with the correct values, similar to "merging" the dict back into the data set. I was hoping to avoid this step and use the dict values directly in a formula, but perhaps this isn't possible.

Comment: Here's the code so far, reading in the data and creating the dicts:
`code`
df=read_csv("TeachingData.csv")
ts=list(df.teacher_id.drop_duplicates())
tdict = {t:random() for t in ts}

sdict=dict(df.correct.groupby(df.student_id).mean())
`code`

Comment: I'm not sure you can, this is probably the most efficient way as merging will copy the source dataframe I think and map on a series is highly optimised as it is written using cython. If you are happy with this answer then you can upvote and accept it.

Comment: @DavidEpstein you could use a function and apply it to the dataframe but I'm not sure you would save much time, it would depend on how many unique ids there were, once you have created the dicts then using `map` is really fast

Comment: Thanks, Ed. The map solution did word, and it's fast, so I'm happy.